# grep fixed string at end of line

Tags: text-processing, grep

I need to `grep` for string containing special characters and make sure it is at the end of the line

For example, in list:

- abc defg[h]ij
  I want to grep for `defg[h]ij$`
- xyz 123*456
  I want to grep for `123*456$`

The search string and possible match containing special characters are varying, thus a fixed masking is not possible.

I am looking for something like `grep -F` in combination with the end of line `$` anchor. `-w` will not suffice, it must be end of line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One approach is to escape those special characters before calling `grep`.

With `zsh`:

```
string='123*.$[]'
grep -e "${string//(#m)[[^.\\\$*]/\\$MATCH}\$" file
```

or POSIXly:

```
escaped_string=$(printf '%s\n' "$string" | sed 's/[[^.\$*]/\\&/g')
grep -e "$escaped_string\$" file
```

or supposing the `$string` doesn't contain `\E`, with GNU `grep` or `pcregrep`:

```
grep -Pe "\Q$string\E\$" file
```

or you could use `awk` like:

```
STRING="$string" awk 'BEGIN {s = ENVIRON["STRING"]; n = length(s)}
                      length >= n && substr($0, length - n + 1, n) == s'
```

or `perl`:

```
STRING="$string" perl -ne 'print if /\Q$ENV{"STRING"}\E$/'
```

(this time, `perl` knows that a `\E` found in `$ENV{"STRING"}` doesn't mark the end of the \Quoted string).

Comment: thx will use the posix approach but use:  `sed 's/[]\/$*.^|[]/\\&/g'`  to escape "]" as well some other

Comment: @PeterK, no, if you turn `|` into `\|` then you make an ordinary character (`|` is not special for `grep` without `-E`) into a regexp operator with some grep implementation (`\|` is an alternation operator in GNU grep for instance). `/` is not special in any `grep` implementation. `]` alone is not special either.